# My program does not accept numbers bigger than 999 99

Tags: java, input, numbers

So I am making an interest calculator for my CPSC class in college first year, things are kinda moving fast and I almost feel like I'm not cut out for this future but I will continue to try until I get it right. However, there is one issue that I can't overcome. Basically, I am trying to input around 999 99 or more but it won't accept it. Lower numbers are accepted however higher ones aren't well even just numbers like 9000. Earlier I was trying to type cast but nothing was working. Any tips on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

```
    final double withDraw = 500;
    double  moneySum = 0;
    int month = 0;
    double EPS = 0.000000000000001;
    int year = 0;
    // all the needed variables

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Starting the first scanner input
    System.out.print("Now input the sum of money in the bank account: ");
    moneySum = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();

    while (moneySum > EPS) {

        month = month + 1;
        moneySum = moneySum * (1 + 0.06 / 12);
        moneySum = moneySum - withDraw;

    }

    for (int i = 0; month > 12; i++) {

        month = month / 12;
        year = month + i;

    }
    // Work on this to make sure things are plural when they should be and singular
    // when they should be
    if (year > 0) {
        System.out.println("Your money will last " + year + " years and " + month + " months");
    } else if (year <= 0) {
        System.out.println("your money will last " + month + " months");
    } else if (month <= 1) {
        System.out.println("Your money will last " + month + "months");
    } else if (month == 1 && year == 1) {
        System.out.println("Your money will last one year and one month");
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "won't accept it" mean?

Comment: You should describe the exact behavior (_i.e._ output) for a given input, and explain what you expect. Otherwise it's very difficult to unpack what you're saying. Note that `999 99` is _two_ numbers. Also, your for-loop could be rewritten with modulo arithmetic instead of looping.

Comment: Do not close you stdin Scanner `input.close();
`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in the following part of your code:

```
 while (moneySum > EPS) {

    month = month + 1;
    moneySum = moneySum * (1 + 0.06 / 12);
    moneySum = moneySum - withDraw;

}
```

Imagine what happens when `moneySum` is very large, at the end of each iteration of the `while` loop. Let's say you input `moneySum = 1000000`, then it gets updated like so:

```
final double withDraw = 500;
moneySum = 1000000; // from input

while (moneySum > EPS) {
   month = month + 1;
   moneySum = moneySum * (1 + 0.06 / 12); // 1005000
   moneySum = moneySum - withDraw; // 1004500
   // moneySum is now larger than it was before,
   //  it will thus keep increasing indefinitely
}
```

After each iteration, `moneySum` only increases, but your loop condition checks whether `moneySum` decreases to below `EPS = 0.000000000000001`, which will never happen.

To fix this issue, make sure you account for this possibility in your loop, it's the special case where you "never run out of money". Like this:

```
while (moneySum > EPS) {
    month = month + 1;
    double newMoneySum = moneySum * (1 + 0.06 / 12) - withDraw;
    if (newMoneySum < moneySum)
        moneySum = newMoneySum;
    else {
        month = -1; // this is so we can check for this condition later
        year = -1;  // feel free to implement it however you like
        break; // this will exit the while loop, regardless of the loop condition
    }
}

for (int i = 0; month > 12; i++) {

    month = month / 12;
    year = month + i;

}

if (year < 0 && month < 0) {
    System.out.println("Your money will last you forever!");
} else if (year > 0) {
    System.out.println("Your money will last " + year + " years and " + month + " months");
} else if (year <= 0) {
    System.out.println("your money will last " + month + " months");
} else if (month <= 1) {
    System.out.println("Your money will last " + month + "months");
} else if (month == 1 && year == 1) {
    System.out.println("Your money will last one year and one month");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Feel free to implement it differently as well, helps with learning :)

Comment: Note that an unproperly checked while loop will make your program hang and never complete, so make sure you always let your loop finish one way or another.